# How to get the index of one specific element within an javascript object

Tags: javascript, php

I have been working on this problem for the second day now and I simply can't seem to find the right way to do it.

**Problem**:
I need to send the index value of a chosen element within a javascript object to an action in PHP. So when the user chooses a certain element, the index value of said element within the object should be send to the mentioned PHP action.

What I have so far is the following:

The button for the jump:

```
<!-- Button to jumpo tp specific dashboard. The select and and option tags will be generated dynamicly -->
<div style="float:right; margin-right: 10px;">
<select name="idDashboards" id="idDashboards">
  <option value="">Jump to Dashboard</option>
</select>
</div>
```

The Array itself as well as how the HTML elements are created

```
// The array with the dashboards as I get it from the server
var dashboardArray = <?php echo json_encode(CHtml::listData($dashboards, 'iddashboard', 'title')); ?>;

// Loop through the elements in the dashboardArray and then create option elements to be added to the above create select element.
  for (var idDashboard in dashboardArray) {
    $('#idDashboards').append($(document.createElement('option')).prop({
      value: idDashboard,
      text: dashboardArray[idDashboard].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + dashboardArray[idDashboard].slice(1)
    }));
  };
```

How the object looks like when I log it.

```
{2: "Dashboard_Test_1", 3: "Dashboard_Test_2", 4: "Dashboard_Test_3", 6: "Dashboard_Test_4"}
```

What I have been trying so far:

```
var dashboardIndex = -1;
var i;

// Loop to get the indexes.
 for (i in dashboardArray) {
   if (dashboardArray.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
     dashboardIndex++
     console.log(dashboardIndex+" These are the indexes");
   }
 }

// Ajax request that sends data to the PHP action
$("#idDashboards").change(function() {
    var idDashboard = $(this).val();
    console.log("The change happened!");
    $.ajax({
      url: 'Path/To/PHP/File/And/Action=' + dashboardIndex,
      method: 'GET',
      success: function(result) {
        location.reload();
        console.log("So far, so good!");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Now, the dashboardIndex and the index of the elements in the object align and are good. But how do I send the index value of only the element that has been chosen by the user?

I am very sorry if this is a duplicate but I could not find anything helpful so far. Every advice/help is appreciated.

Comment: What variable would hold the selected element?

Comment: You can use Object.entries to get the keys and the values of the Object. So you can check if the value is the one selected by the user, and if it is, you can use its key and do whatever you want with it. Link to docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries, hope I understand your question correctly.

Comment: @Rojo It would be the idDashboard. This one is a simple integer. However, it is the id of the selected dashboard.
I also edited the question a bit. Excuse me if I don't understand you right. Not native english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `change` function, you should be able to use `$(this).prop('selectedIndex')` to get the index of the item you selected.

I am curious, however, why the API is looking for the *index* of the dashboard rather than the seemingly unique ID that your API is initially responding with. This may be a more resilient approach.

Comment: Works like a charm. No idea you could do this. As to why I have to use the index instead of the id. It is because of the backend that has been used. It would be to much to change all the code that is linked to the backend in this particular case.
I am already working on fixing it for the future, so I don't have to do such things anymore.
Anyways, thanks a lot.